# Why the datatype changed when invoking a UDF in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df:

```
joined.printSchema
root
 |-- cc_num: long (nullable = true)
 |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- long: double (nullable = true)
 |-- merch_lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- merch_long: double (nullable = true)
```

I have a udf:

```
def getDistance (lat1:Double, lon1:Double, lat2:Double, lon2:Double) = {
    val r : Int = 6371 //Earth radius
    val latDistance : Double = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1)
    val lonDistance : Double = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1)
    val a : Double = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2)
    val c : Double = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))
    val distance : Double = r * c
    distance
  }
```

I need to generate a new column to the df with:

```
joined = joined.withColumn("distance", getDistance("lat", "long", "merch_lat", "merch_long"))
```

I received error below:

```
Name: Unknown Error
Message: <console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("lat")
 required: Double
       joined = joined.withColumn("distance", getDistance("lat", "long", "merch_lat", "merch_long"))
                                                          ^
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("long")
 required: Double
       joined = joined.withColumn("distance", getDistance("lat", "long", "merch_lat", "merch_long"))
                                                                 ^
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("merch_lat")
 required: Double
       joined = joined.withColumn("distance", getDistance("lat", "long", "merch_lat", "merch_long"))
                                                                         ^
<console>:35: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("merch_long")
 required: Double
       joined = joined.withColumn("distance", getDistance("lat", "long", "merch_lat", "merch_long"))
                                                                                      ^
```

As you can see from the schema, all involved fields are type of `double`, which meets the udf's parameter type definition, why I am seeing the data type mismatch error?

Can anyone enlighten here what is wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getDistance` method is NOT a UDF, it's a Scala method expecting 4 `Double` arguments, and you're passing 4 strings instead.

To fix this, you need to:

- "Wrap" your method with a UDF, and
- Pass *column* arguments and not Strings when applying the UDF, which you can do by prefixing the column name with `$`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._ // assuming "spark" is your SparkSession

val distanceUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf(getDistance _)

joined.withColumn("distance", distanceUdf($"lat", $"long", $"merch_lat", $"merch_long"))
```

Comment: You'll need to import `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction` too; And I assumed `spark` is how your SparkSession is named; If it's named differently, replace `spark` with a reference to the session. Importing the session's implicits is not a must but very helpful.